# Rewrite wildcard rule to redirect images that works with HTTP, HTTPS and Firefox HTTPS-Only mode

Tags: htaccess, https, firefox, regex

This set of rules causes the nolinks.jpg image to appear if anyone tries to link directly to an image from a remote site.  It is working well but with the latest Firefox, the browser is forced to https rather than http. How can it be made to work whether https, http? I rarely use regular expressions so not sure how to apply them here.

```
# Block external links
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?domain1\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?domain1\.net/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?domain1\.org/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?domain2\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?domain2\.net/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?domain2\.org/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?devdomain\.dev/ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule show_image\.php http://www.domain1.com/nolinks.jpg? [R=301,QSA]
```

If forced to https, the image would have to link to https too. Also, it needs to work whether www or no www. How is this done?

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Just a few basic things like AddType and ErrorDocument but no other rewrite-related directives.

Comment: "the browser seems to get stuck trying and keeps going to https rather than http" - What do you mean exactly by this? Are you seeing a 3xx redirect in the network traffic (in the browser)? Is your site accessible on HTTPS?

Comment: it is likely caused by [HTTPS-only mode](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2020/11/17/firefox-83-introduces-https-only-mode/) which was introduced in FF 83.   Does your site support HTTPS?  If not, you probably need to add HTTPS support to fix this issue.

Comment: I know that it's caused by the Firefox change (which is ridiculous) but I can't tell every site visitor to disable it so the .htaccess which is not working due to this change is what I am trying to fix. Fortunately the site is accessible by https but wouldn't have been a few months ago so the only real problem is my own .htaccess making none of the images show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in the directives you've posted that would cause this directly. Throwing a regex at this isn't going help. The `RewriteRule` directive you posted redirects to `http` - end of. So, any "redirect" to HTTPS is coming from somewhere else.

You need to examine the HTTP request/response headers in the browser. Are you actually seeing a 3xx redirect or is the browser "upgrading" the request? Are you sending a `Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests;` HTTP response header? Or even `Strict-Transport-Security` header (although that is only relevant when sent over HTTPS). Have you dabbled with [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) in the past?!

> sometimes, especially with the latest Firefox

However, the fact that this appears to be *intermittent* and browser dependent would seem to suggest the problem is elsewhere and harder to debug.

Since the "big push" to HTTPS everywhere, it seems strange that any site would be hotlinking an HTTP image - this would cause problems if the source site is HTTPS. Maybe the source site is triggering the *upgrade*/redirect to HTTPS?!

However, there are some concerns with the directives as posted.

1. There is no `L` flag on the `RewriteRule`, so processing is going to continue through the file and potentially be rewritten or redirected by later directives. In other words, there could be a conflict with other directives. However, you've stated that there are "no other rewrite-related directives" - so that would seem to rule out this possibility. Although it is the most likely one.

   ```
   [R=301,L]
   ```
2. You've included the `QSA` flag on the `RewriteRule` *and* included a trailing `?` on the *substitution* string (ie. `/nolinks.jpg?`). This is really a *contradiction*. The trailing `?` effectively removes any query string from the original request, but the `QSA` flag appends it again! You would get the same result without the trailing `?` and without the `QSA` flag, however, you do want to remove the query string. So, you should keep the trailing `?` and remove the `QSA` flag. Or, use the `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag instead on Apache 2.4.

   ```
   RewriteRule show_image\.php http://www.domain1.com/nolinks.jpg [QSD,R=301,L]
   ```
3. You are using a 301 (permanent) redirect. This reduces the hits to your server as the redirect response should be cached by the browser. However, it also means that if a user should visit a site that is hotlinking your images and they are redirected to `nolinks.jpg` then they will also be redirected when they visit *your* site and will be unable to see your images. You would need to change this to a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid this behaviour - but maybe that's considered an edge case and you want to keep this "permanent". However, a "cached redirect" could perhaps
4. You are redirecting to HTTP and checking HTTP in the `Referer` header in all your conditions. Are you not using HTTPS on any of your sites?!
5. Instead of *redirecting* to another image, it would be far more efficient and less resource-intensive (part of the reason for creating a hotlink protection script in the first place) if you simply block (403 Forbidden) the request instead. For example:

   ```
   RewriteRule show_image\.php - [F]
   ```
6. The use of `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$` is arguably necessary since some users might suppress the HTTP `Referer` and without this *condition* they would not be able to see your images. Although you could argue that the user knows what they are doing in this case and have made the intentioned decision that they may not see some images. However, this *condition* also allows a site that is hotlinking your images to set a [Referrer-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) that suppresses the `Referer` and overrides your hotlinking script!

---

**UPDATE:**

> ...caused by [HTTPS-only mode](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2020/11/17/firefox-83-introduces-https-only-mode/) which was introduced in FF 83 ....  Fortunately **the site is accessible by https** ... so the only real problem is my own .htaccess making none of the images show up. ... the .htaccess rewrite rules to work whether http or https

Ah, in that case, as touched on in #4 above, you need to modify all instances of `http` in the `RewriteCond` directives to `https?` - the `?` *quantifier* makes the `s` *optional*.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(.+\.)?domain1\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(.+\.)?domain1\.net/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(.+\.)?domain1\.org/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(.+\.)?domain2\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(.+\.)?domain2\.net/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(.+\.)?domain2\.org/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(.+\.)?devdomain\.dev/ [NC]
```

Whether you change the `http` (to `https`) in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string is really up to you (if you are not *forcing* HTTPS on your site)¹:

```
RewriteRule show_image\.php https://www.domain1.com/nolinks.jpg? [R=301,L]
```

(NB: Just `https`, not `https?` in the *substitution* string.)

¹ But note that if you redirect to plain HTTP then any HTTPS site that hotlinks your image(s) - where the user is *not* using "HTTPS-only mode" in Fx (or similar plugin in other browsers) - will get a "mixed content" warning in their browser and the `nolinks.jpg` image won't display.

Or, simply block the request (preferable from a server perspective) as mentioned in #5 above:

```
RewriteRule show_image\.php - [F]
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I know it's nothing to do with the directives but the rewrite rule expects http rather than https so when it gets https as the browser is forcing it to do, it shows the nolinks.jpg image.

Comment: The site is NOT https and was never designed to be. It is also a legacy site originally written on the mid-'90s and rewritten several times since but fortunately after recently changing hosting companies it will run as https. If run as https, the links.jpg could also be loaded that way but where I need the help is for the ,htaccess rewrite rules to work whether http or https. On the intermittent part, that may be due to cashing that it seems to sometimes work and not related to the problem. I know that this can be overridden so the rewrite is for "casual bandwidth thieves" rather than pros.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: That worked perfectly and was exactly what I was looking for! However, I now see that it works only when no www. How can I make it work whether www or not? (I’ll append this to my question too.)

Comment: You mean when navigating _your_ site with no www? HTTP or HTTPS or both? What happens exactly? The regex `(.+\.)?` should already handle this situation (in fact, it allows _any_ subdomain). Make sure you are not seeing a cached response - since this is a 301 (permanent) redirect any "erroneous" redirects in the last few days/weeks will have also been cached by the browser.

Comment: I thought that's what the `(.+\.)?` was for but then when it didn't seem to work, I began to winder! It was written years ago when I still had good memory. In Firefox I can't load the site with only http (even though my other sites still seem able) as it just switches automatically to https. Anyway, you're right, it was cache. I had cleared it but finally went to the security settings and removed all off-line content, then it worked as it should. Thank you!